# how to integrate $ \int_\frac74^2 \lvert 1-x\rvert dx $ manully?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, education

I calculated it on https://www.integral-calculator.com/
$$
\int_{7/4}^{2}\left\lvert 1 - x\right\rvert\mathrm{d}x
$$
and got the answer but I could not get the answer right when substituting.
Also, it would be very helpful if there were another way to do the integration instead of the solution given by the site

Comment: Please enclose your equation with dollar symbols to display formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get a grasp of the situation (in my opinion) would be to graph the integrand over the given interval:

[image]

The vertical lines represent the bounds of your integration, and the red graph is $f(x) = |1-x|$. Recalling that the integral just gives the signed area under a curve, if you can find the area of the green trapezoid, you can find the value of the integral.

(Of course, you can also just note as Adam did that, on $(7/4,2)$, $|1-x| = x-1$, and so you can perform a more standard integral that way. I prefer this geometric explanation, but the algebraic idea is also nice.)

Comment: Yeah I prefer this answer to mine. I just cba to draw a graph. Where did you get the image of that graph from?

Comment: I just drew it in Desmos and tweaked it a bit in MS Paint

Comment: Desmos eh? Neat

Comment: thanx, it was very clear that way

Answer (score 3):

$\lvert 1-x\rvert = -1+x$ when $x\geq1$

Comment: thanx, but x is not limited

Comment: Yes it is, by the bounds of your integration -- that is, $7/4 < x < 2$, because of the bounds

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but should not the absolute introduce a negative part, and can you please explain how would the substitution go in this case, in the mentioned site I got $ \dfrac{17}{32} $

Comment: I dunno how your website works, but the answer is $7/32$. "should not the absolute introduce a negative part" What do you mean by this? "And can you please explain how would the substitution go in this case" You substitute $\lvert 1-x\rvert$ with $-1+x$ because these two expressions are equal for all $x \geq 1$. This is true using the definition of $\lvert \ \cdot\ \rvert$

Comment: @MarcAziz The absolute value function $|\cdot |: x\mapsto |x|$ is defined as $|x|=x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x<0$.